# JWPlayer keep video proportional when user clicks Full-Screen

Tags: video, jwplayer

Video is correctly proportioned when displayed normally, but when the user clicks full screen, the video is expanded literally to the full screen without regard for the original video's proportion.

Is there a way to ensure that the video retains its proportions when going to full screen?  Adding black space at the top /bottom or sides depending on the video display vs screen display?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle or any other link for this problem

Comment: Are you using jwplayer API for width and height in setup ?

Comment: It might be some css conflict in your code ... to help I need to see your code or share some link which will help in debugging

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to set the height and width in jwplayer setup

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://example.com/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
        image: "http://example.com/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

Here is the [API](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-mp4-video-embed)

Let me know if it helps.